# hbase migration to 0.98 ClassNotFoundException WritableByteArrayComparable

Tags: migration, hbase, noclassdeffounderror

After recent migration from `HBase 0.94.13` to `HBase 0.98.12` my code is failing to execute.

I am simply trying to connect to a table via dependent jar file developed by another team who uses Spring HbaseTemplate. I have manually placed all the required jar files for executing the code including `hbase-client-0.98.12-mapr-1506.jar` (we have MapR distribution).

I am receiving the following error:

> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/WritableByteArrayComparable

It seems to be occuring because `HBase 0.96.x WritableByteArrayComparable` has been renamed to `ByteArrayComparable`.

How can I make the old code work again?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work by keeping the old jar hbase-0.94.9-mapr-1308 in the classpath. It was a dirty fix but it did the job.

The other team whose dependent jar I was using to connect to M7, finally updated their code and now things are back to normal again. Thanks.